# PhD Spring Admission

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

Is there any university in the US offers PhD admission for the Spring? I'm trying to apply for the Cell and Molecular Biology at any university in the US

Answer (score 4):

Not any place reputable. All of the reputable schools follow the standard application schedule of Nov-Dec deadlines and spring notifications for matriculation in the fall.

There may be some online or non-traditional schools with rolling deadlines, however these should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Florida Atlantic University and Tennessee State University admit students in the Spring semester for PhD program.